# AppBarLayout/Toolbar not showing (height = 0)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am developing an app to display details about movie/tv shows. When opening the movie from search results it opens correctly. Then I add the movie to my collection, turns to MainActivity where all my movies are listed. Selecting the same movie, but now the entire AppBarLayout is hidden! I don't get any exceptions of any kind, in debug I see that it is visible, but has height of 0. Why is this happening?

I have a method that collapses the CollapsingToolbarLayout if no banner image is found, but this is not the case here. It should anyhow have a toolbar with title when collapsed, and expand on scroll.

### [image: Correctly displayed] [image: AppBarLayout not visible]

Layout of DetailActivity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".activites.DetailActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_spring_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="60dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/banner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NestedFixFlingScrollView
[...]
```

Some relevant setup methods in DetailActivity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    movieChanges = InterfaceHolder.movieChanges;
    findNodes();
    setupToolbar();
    setupCurrentMovie();
    setupImageGallery();
    setupFAB();

    displayDetails();
    fetchTmdbDetails();
}

private void setupToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    setTitleWhenCollapsed();
}

private void setupCurrentMovie() {
    movie = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MOVIE), Movie.class);
    if (movie == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.movie_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
[...]
```

Starting DetailActivity from search result:

```
holder.listItemContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (resultModel.searchResult.isTvShow() || resultModel.searchResult.isMovie()) {
                final Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(resultModel.displayText);
                movie.setYear(resultModel.year);
                movie.setFormat(MovieFormat.BLU_RAY);
                movie.setType(MediaType.from(resultModel.mediaType));
                movie.setPosterPath(resultModel.posterUrl);
                movie.setTmdbId(resultModel.searchResult.getId());
                final Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, new Gson().toJson(movie));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Starting from MainActivity:

```
final Movie movie = movieList().get(position);
final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_MOVIE, new Gson().toJson(movie));
startActivity(intent);
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

styles.xml-21:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme21" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Both the SearchActivitiy and DetailActivity uses AppTheme.NoActionBar. MainActivity uses AppTheme. I now noticed that when opening a movie from SearchActivity it is showing correctly, but if I press back (to search) and then opens the same movie again, it does not show correctly.

I had some suspicion that it whould be this line in the SearchActivity that caused the trouble, but it was not:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

It seems that it is only after using the SearchActivity that the DetailActivity does not show correctly. All of my other example data in MainActivity opens correctly in DetailActivity, until i have used the SearchActivity. Even some of the movies that I have not searched for.

---

Sorry if this question grew to be to long/detailed, but I often see that people are asking for more details, so I chose to include as much relevant info as I thought was necessary.

Please let me know if you need any more info?

Comment: what about ur theme?

Comment: Uguboz, I have updated the question with my themes and some more info.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try removing android:fitsSystemWindows="true" of banner ImageView, u already have it in the appbar.

Comment: Uguboz, if I remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from banner ImageView the statusbar gets a solid color, not transparent anymore. Besides, it does not fix the problem with the appbar not showing after using SearchActivity. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! 
I am using Ion for image loading, and had a callback method "collapseAppBarOnError":

```
private FutureCallback<ImageView> collapseAppBarOnError() {
    return new FutureCallback<ImageView>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, ImageView result) {
            stopLoading();
            if (e != null && !(e instanceof CancellationException)) {//TODO: Denne vil ikke funke om errorDrawable ligger i cache?
                collapse();
            } else if (result != null && result.getDrawable() != null && !result.getDrawable().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_movie_white_48dp))) {
                expand();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It was the "else if" in the callback method that caused the trouble. Sorry, for this was impossible for you guys to see when I had not postet all my code.

It turns out that it actually had nothing to do with the SearchActivity, the error was also happening if I opened a movie I already had in my collection two times or more, even if not using the search! It worked correctly the first time, but not the following times.